# Equation of $q$ dimensional plane containing $q + 1$ points in $R^n$ where $q \leq n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let there be $q+1$ points $X_i = (x_{i1}, x_{i2}, ... x_{in})$ ($0 \le i \le q$) in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Assume that the points $X_i$ are all LI.

What is the equation of the $q$ dimensional hyperplane defined by these q+1 points?

I know that if $q = n$, then the equation is given by:
$\det\begin{vmatrix}x_1 &x_2 &... &x_n &1 \\ x_{11} &x_{12} &... &x_{1n} &1 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
x_{n1} &x_{n2} &... &x_{nn} &1 \\\end{vmatrix} = 0$.

But if $q < n$, the matrix is no longer a square matrix, so we can't take determinant ! What is the required equation in this case?

Comment: So, you want the $q$-dimensional affine subspace (i.e. like a plane, but not necessarily dimension $2$) defined by $q + 1$ vectors? If that's true, then you won't be able to characterise this set with a single linear equation, and can be presented in a few different forms. What kind of answer are you hoping for here?

Comment: @TheoBendit Maybe as the intersection of 'how-many-ever' n-dimensional hyperplanes? So like the equation of a 2D line x - 2y = 3 in 3D can be written as x - 2 y + 0z = 3 /\ z = 0.

Comment: Ah yes, so a system of $n - q + 1$ linear equations. I don't know of any formulas as straightforward as the determinant formula given, but I'll think about it if I get a spare moment. (By the way, `\land` is the command for "logical and" in mathjax.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with taking more equations than are required, then take all $q+1$ sized determinants of the $(q+1)\times (n+1)$ matrix as you have written and put them equal to $0$.

This is a necessary and sufficient condition for the first row to be linearly dependent on the remaining $q$ rows when those rows are linearly independent.

This linear dependence condition is the same as saying that the point given by the first $n$ entries of this row lie in the affine linear space spanned by the $q$ vectors.

Comment: Do we need to take all (q+1) sized determinants or will just n-q+1 minors corresponding to the same row suffice?

Comment: @Kaind To select $n-q+1$ you will need to determine a $q\times q$ minor of the $q\times n$ matrix to see which one is non-zero.